# I can’t see the ropsten test network on my meta mask

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, metamask, decentralized-applications

I can’t see the ropsten test network on my meta mask.
I tried to distribute my dapp on the test net using ropsten, but I faced this problem.

The test network show option is active.

Please understand that my lang is korean. :o
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alsU5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Rinkeby, Kovan and Ropsten have been deprecated (see announcements on [Ethereum.org](https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/06/21/testnet-deprecation) and [Infura.io](https://blog.infura.io/post/deprecation-timeline-for-rinkeby-ropsten-and-kovan-testnets)). Because of this, MetaMask also removed these networks from their default list. It is recommended to use Goerli or Sepolia instead of any of these deprecated testnets.

Comment: thank you. i used Goerli.